# How to close MongoDB connection in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP mongoDB driver ver 1.1.8
My PHP code for establishing a connection to MongoDB goes like this

```
$conn=new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

But the problem is , each time a client refresh the page a new connection is established. Therefore i want to close the connection at the end of the PHP script.

Earlier i used to close a connection with this code

```
$conn->close();
```

But this is not working in the new PHP MongoDB drivers.

Comment: The $conn->close(); is still the documented way. How do you know it's not working? Do you get some error after calling $conn->close();?

Comment: @BojanBedrač yea ,Fatal error :  Call to undefined method MongoDB\Client::close()

Comment: True, there is no more close method on the Client. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Client.php

The client is using the Manager, so that might be the way.

Although you might not need to close it, the driver should take care of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174096/what-happens-when-connections-to-mongodb-are-not-closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$conn->close();` is **out dated** and *will not work* with current driver.

**The new driver is designed to leave connections open**, and there is no method of turning that off.

Refer [This](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/393)

Comment: Thank you, extremely helpful! +1